# how to import @mdi/font to my vue3 project without vuetify?

Tags: mdi, vuejs3

I installed @mdi/font using
`npm i @mdi/font`

But how can i import it to my vue3 Project?
vite return warning:

```
[vite] dependency @mdi/font declares non-existent entry file D:\xxxx\node_modules\@mdi\font\index.js.
```

What should I do so that i can use mdi icons like this way
  `<span class="mdi mdi-account-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>`

Comment: how do you import it?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim i add it by import it from cdn just add the stylesheet link into head ,but now i want to import it from what i download by npm install @mdi/font

Comment: You should import style by `import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'` instead of `import '@mdi/font'`

Answer (score -1):

if you dont want to pack the font to your project,just add cdn link to your index.html in public folder like this:

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
```